# How to remove an exception error when subtracting 8 from a variable?

Tags: prolog

I am writing a program in prolog, in which the name and marks of some students can be entered. The marks of some of these students can be altered if certain conditions are met. In this case, 'albert' likes a girl. If she doesn't like him back he becomes sad and does not do as well on the test, thus losing marks.

```
student(albert, stone, 86).
student(rebecca, eudder, 21).
student(jamie, warner, 69).

likes(albert, rebecca).
dating(rebecca, jamie).

sad(albert) :-
    likes(albert, rebecca),
    dating(rebecca, X).

lostmarks(albert).
    sad(albert),
    student(albert, stone, Y),
    Y - 8.
```

When I run the `lostmarks(albert)` rule I receive this error *uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,(-)/2),lostmarks/0)*

Answer (score 1):

An arithmetic expression is not a goal, hence the exception you got. Try instead something like:

```
lostmarks(albert, NewMarks).
    sad(albert),
    student(albert, stone, Marks),
    NewMarks  is Marks - 8.
```

Next, generalize the predicate to work for any student. For example:

```
lostmarks(FirstName, LastName, NewMarks).
    sad(FirstName),
    student(FirstName, LastName, Marks),
    NewMarks  is Marks - 8.
```

But it's odd that `student/1` only takes the first name...